# .htaccess redirect for url with parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have searched around for this but not finding what I need. Basically any url which has `?` at the end followed by further characters should be redirected to another url, the same path excluding the language though. An example will make it clearer.

If a user lands on `https://example.com/fr/contact-us/?utm_medium=email`

they should be redirected to `https://example.com/contact-us/?utm_medium=email`

and that should be the case for any url with `?` in it after the last `/`

Unfortunately I don't know that much about redirects so I don't have a great attempt here.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_medium=\d+$
RewriteRule ..... [R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically any url which has ? at the end followed by further characters should be redirected to another url, the same path excluding the language though.

You may use this redirect rule:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.*) /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Here:

- `%{QUERY_STRING} .` makes sure there is non-empty query string
- `[a-z]{2}/` matches any 2 letter language code followed by a `/`
- Query string is automatically copied over to the target URL.